# postgres faster query to update using self join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, self-join

I have a table named **feature** like bellow,

```
+--------------------+---------+
| Column             | Type    |
|--------------------+---------+
| id                 | bigint  |
| type               | bigint  |
| oid                | bigint  |
| level              | bigint  |
| flag               | bigint  |
+--------------------+---------+
Indexes:
    "feature_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "flag_idx" btree (flag)
    "level_idx" btree (level)
    "oid_idx" btree (oid)
    "type" btree (type)
```

I need to update `level` and `flag`. I am using below query to update.

```
UPDATE feature f
SET level = f1.level,
flag = f1.flag
from feature f1
where f.oid = f1.oid
and f.type = 5
and f1.type = 1;
```

Here is my query plan.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                       |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Update on feature f  (cost=0.85..16.90 rows=1 width=470)                                         |
|   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..16.90 rows=1 width=470)                                           |
|         ->  Index Scan using type on feature f  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=448)               |
|               Index Cond: (type = 5)                                                             |
|         ->  Index Scan using oid_idx on feature f1  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=30)            |
|               Index Cond: (oid = f.oid)                                                          |
|               Filter: (type = 1)                                                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Table contains some 10M rows. It is taking hours(more than 10hrs) to update the columns.

Am I doing anything  wrong here? How to fasten my query?

Comment: post execution plan.  I would start by creating an index on oid, type, level, flag

Comment: Drop your indexes and do the update, then re-apply the indexes

Comment: @vol7ron does index really affects update operation this much(like > 10 hrs)?

Comment: If you have a lot of indexes, or complex ones (GiST / GIN, big multi-column indexes, etc) then on a big table it sure can.

Comment: 10M rows isn't insignificant.  I don't know what your hardware is like, but this is one case where you can easily test it without hurting anything.  Every time you update a table with an index, it may be writing to more than one table (source and index).  You might be saving time by doing the index scan, but losing time when writing.

Comment: I am running this on my development machine, mac book pro, 8gigs ram, 256gigs ssd.

Comment: @vol7ron Yes, Index was the culprit. Now update happens in minutes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected result. I think that query can be simplified but without a clear description on what you actually want to do it's hard tell

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The *name* `oid` is not deprecated. Using *type* `oid` for a primary key is.

Comment: How many source tuples will satisfy your conditions? (for every target tuple)